# Трюк с наследованием

Tags: наследование, классы, css

Не понимаю в чем отличие записи при наследование классов в CSS .

```
.class1.class2{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

или так

```
.class1{
    color:red;
}

.class2{
    font-size:100px;
}
```

Результат получается разный.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kirg/s9eyc30L/7/

Comment: То есть, результат вам ни о чем не сказал?

Comment: есть же такое правило,что все, что ниже по коду , отменяет то,что описано выше!?

Comment: @Kirg то есть, в вашем представлении вообще все должно отмениться?)))))))) Остаться должен только один! (С)

Comment: нет, но это объясняет  почему первый перечёркнут, а не подчёркнут.
http://jsfiddle.net/Kirg/s9eyc30L/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.class1.class2` будет применен к блоку, которые имеет сразу два класса на себе `class1` и `class2`.

`.class1` будет применен к тому блоку, где есть класс `class1`. Логично предположить, что блок <div class="class1 class2"> применит к себе эти стили. Так же и с `.class2`.

Если у вас блок просто `<div class="class1">` (или `.class2`), то стили `.class1.class2` не будут применены.

---

О чем должен говорить результат?

```
.class1{
    color:red;
}
```

Цвет в блоках, где есть этот класс красный? Красный.

```
.class2{
    font-size:100px;
}
```

Размер текста 100px где есть этот класс? 100px.

```
.class3{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Текст подчеркнутый в блоке, где есть этот класс? Нет. Почему? Потому что ниже

```
.class1.class2{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Перечеркнутый? Не подчеркнутый? Да. Почему? Потому что приоритет стилей снизу вверх по файлу стилей.

```
.class1 .class2{
    text-shadow: 3px 3px #ff0000;
}
```

Тень есть у блока с классом .class2, который находится в блоке с классом .class1? Да.

Ну все. Не знаю, какие могут быть вопросы еще))

Comment: Спасибо. Не скажу,что понял все четко . Вот так - правильно размышляю ?


.class1.class2{             /* как одно название класса*/
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.class1 .class2{  /* перечисление через пробел применяемых классов*/
    text-shadow: 3px 3px #ff0000;
}

Comment: @Kirg Второй вариант применится к блок class2, который лежит внутри .class1

Comment: @Kirg ловите апдейт ответа)

Comment: Прекрасно ! Благодарю !